# How to force scanf to match whitespace?

Tags: c, scanf, format-specifiers, character-class

I am trying to use `fscanf()` to read in a char that *must* be preceded and followed by whitespace:

```
fscanf( input, "%*[ \t]%c%*[ \t]", output )
```

But unfortunately, the `"%*[ \t]"` format specifier accepts zero or more matches.  Is there anyway I can require it to accept at least one match, or do I need to use something like `getc()`?

Comment: `fscanf` and whitespace don't get along very well, so IMO you're better off  with `fgetc` to get a character at a time, or `fgets` to get a line at a time, and then do the parsing yourself.

Comment: `fscanf()` is not for regular expressions matching.

Comment: Something like `char sp1[2], sp2[2], output; if (3 == fscanf( input, "%1[ \t]%c%1[ \t]", sp1, &output, sp2 )) Good();`  yet agree with @user3386109

Comment: BTW: `"%*[ \t]"` does not accept zero matches.

Comment: The `[` specifier fails if zero characters are matched (aborting the read). It might help if you posted some sample input that does not appear to be matching as you expected

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to solve this post with `fscanf()` but let us look at a `fgetc()` approach.

```
// return 1 on success, else return 0
int GetSpaceCharSpace(FILE *istream, int *ch) {
  *ch = fgetc(istream);
  if (!isspace(*ch))
    return 0;

  // consume additional leading spaces as OP said "accept at least one match"
  while (isspace(*ch = fgetc(istream)))
    ;
  // Code has a non-white-space

  // Success if next char is a white-space
  return isspace(fgetc(istream));
}
```